# Visual Web Developer Express 2010 T4 Templates no icon?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

[image: text templating visual studio 2010]

I have installed Visual Web Developer Express 2010 but my .tt templates don't have icons. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug in the Express editions of Visual Studio 2010. The core components of T4 are installed, but registry entries and item templates are missing.